# what all the defalut classes will get invoke the time of creating a dialog

Tags: visual-c++

Could you please any one let me know what all the classes will get invoke at the time of creation of Dailog in Dialog based applications.
 and please let me know the differnce bitween dialog based application and SDI and MDI's.

Answer (score 0):

When the dialog is created only one class is invoked: the CDialog-derived class. A dialog based application is the simplest type of MFC app.

SDI and MDI applications create a frame window, with a menu, tool bar and status bar, a view window (inside the frame), and a document object. MDI also allows the user to open more than one file at a time and creates a document, MDI frame and view for each open document. Several types of view can be used, depending on what you wish to display.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving your responce on the question i asked.